# Calling Parent Class From Sub Class PHP

Tags: php, oop, non-english

[$this->a->b->c->d calling methods from a superclass in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742097/this-a-b-c-d-calling-methods-from-a-superclass-in-php)

Ive asked a question on this link I ve problem with this tecnique I am able to call the sub classes from a class

like this

$chesterx->db->query();

I wanna do get another class from sub class

for example

i want to query execute which was come from the sql class

```
            ROOT
             |
sql <---  chesterx --->  db
```

i wanna use the sql class from db

the problem i cant return the chesterx class from db class

/*edit*/

I have some classes like news, members, categories, db and query

and i did it like the link which was on the subject top

public function __construct(){

```
    function __construct(){  
      if(!$this->db){                                       
                 include(ROOT."/func/class/bp.db.class.php");
                 $this->db = new db;
            }
if(!$this->chester){                                        
                 include(ROOT."/func/class/bp.chester.class.php");
                 $this->db = new chester;
            }
        }
```

i called the db class with this code and now i am able to call and use the db class methods well

for example

i want to use a method from db

that method is containing a value which was returning a data from the chester class's method

i wish i were clarify myself
/*edit*/

is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You'll need to rephrase your question a bit. I don't really understand it.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking for... could you clarify?

Comment: Agreed, a code example would be extremely helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find Ionut G. Stan's solution good for your case, but you might also want to consider the [factory/singleton pattern](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php), though it's only good if your chesterx class is a global one, and only called once

Answer (score 3):

The below snippet might be a solution, although I don't really like the circular reference. Try it and use it as you see fit. And by the way, what you are calling class and subclass are actually *containing and contained class*.

```
class Database
{
    public $chesterx;

    public function __construct($chesterx)
    {
        $this->chesterx = $chesterx;
    }
}

class Sql
{
    public $chesterx;

    public function __construct($chesterx)
    {
        $this->chesterx = $chesterx;
    }
}

class Chesterx
{
    public $db;

    public $sql;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db  = new Database($this);
        $this->sql = new Sql($this);
    }
}
```